# Julia package data files and absolute/relative paths

Tags: julia

I'm creating a package in Julia and have followed the [Package Development](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/#package-development) section of the Docs.

One of my functions opens and reads in a data file (`mydata.txt`) that I'm storing in the package directory.

Everything works pretty great when I run the Julia from the package directory but not so great when I run the tests or run Julia from a different directory because it doesn't know where to find that data file.

I thought I could just do something like:

```
datapath = Pkg.dir("MyPkg") * "/data/"
```

to get an absolute path to the file but it still doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct way to provide an absolute file path for data in a package?

Comment: What OS are you on, what version of Julia, and just how did that not work? Normally, you should use joinpath instead of concatenation when building a directory.

Comment: Mac. Julia 0.4.5. Basically just doesn't find the file. Thanks for the `joinpath` tip, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `joinpath(Pkg.dir("MyPkg"), "data", "mydata.txt")` should work.

Comment: @imaluengo I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @niczky12 Thx! done. Forgot about this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Julia 1.0, the answer by Imanol Luengo will produce a warning:

> Warning: `Pkg.dir(pkgname, paths...)` is deprecated; instead, do `import PackageName; joinpath(dirname(pathof(PackageName)), "..", paths...)`"

so while it still works, it will stop working in a future version. The replacement suggested in the warning message seems to work:

```
joinpath(dirname(pathof(MyPkg)), "..", "data")
```

Inside the package you don't need the import.

Answer (score 6):

In order to properly handle multi-platform directory files and paths, use Julia's built-in `joinpath` method:

```
joinpath(Pkg.dir("MyPkg"), "data", "mydata.txt")
```

The resulting path will be valid in every platform.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Julia 1.0 I get "Warning: `Pkg.dir(pkgname, paths...)` is deprecated; instead, do `import PackageName; joinpath(dirname(pathof(PackageName)), "..", paths...)`", so this is not going to work much longer. Still thinking of a fix, since that won't work inside the package in question…

Comment: To my slight surprise, the above *does* work inside the package, without that import, so that suggestion in the warning message works. I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia 1.7 and above, you can simply do:

```
datapath = pkgdir("MyPkg", "data")
mytxtpath = pkgdir("MyPkg", "data", "mydata.txt")
# etc. - any number of path components are allowed as further arguments
```

For earlier versions (from either 1.3 or 1.4 version), replace `Pkg.dir` in @ImanolLuengo's answer with `pkgdir`:
`joinpath(pkgdir("MyPkg"), "data", "mydata.txt")`